# How to suppress warnings "Command \underbar has changed." and "It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can."?

Tags: warnings, sectsty, silence, filter, extsizes

I would like to use an Overleaf template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/rsc), but it gives a warning for the `\underline` command of `sectsty`. Do you have any idea how to suppress all the warnings of this package? I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler. What I tried is the following:

```
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{latex}{Command}
```

but it doesn't work. I have the same problem with the following message:

```
ExtSizes Warning: It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can.
```